# VSTO Outlook: Make menu not visible within split button

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

In the compose window I have an split button in the ribbon menu. The split button is formed by a button and a menu.

Under some conditions I need to make not visible the menu "myMenu" (hide it) but I want to make the splitButton "MySplitButton" and the button "MyButton" visible. How can I achieve this?

```
      <splitButton id="MySplitButton"
                   size="large">             
        <button id="MyButton"/>
        <menu id="myMenu" getVisible = "IsVisible">
          <toggleButton id="tg1" />
          <toggleButton id="tg2" />
        </menu>
      </splitButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `getVisible` callback for the `menu` control like you have in your ribbon XML now. The callback should have the following signature:

```
C#: bool GetVisible(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)

C++: HRESULT GetVisible([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *pvarfVisible)

Visual Basic: Function GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean
```

In the callback you need to set the `visible` parameter to `false` if you want to hide the menu and `true` for bringing it back.

Be aware, for each of the callbacks that the add-in implements, the responses are cached. That means if an add-in writer implements the `getVisible` callback procedure for a menu, the function is called once, the visible state is set, and then if the visible state needs to be updated, the cached value/state is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.

To update the UI you may find the [IRibbonUI.Invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidate) and [IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol) methods helpful. An instance of the `IRibbonUI` interface is passed to the `onLoad` callback:

```
C#: void OnLoad(IRibbonUI ribbon)

VBA: Sub OnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)

C++: HRESULT OnLoad([in] IRibbonUI *pRibbon)

Visual Basic: Function OnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
```

So, you can save a reference for future use in the add-in for invalidating the state of controls.

Comment: I have seen that when I set menu to hide (no visible) then the entire split button is make not visible as well. Where is the OnLoad event?

Comment: That is for the `customUI` element.